# Android music player that doesn't show full-screen album art

Tags: android, music, media-player, privacy

When I play or choose music from my phone in public (using headphones, of course), I don't like how the album art is displayed in most players - usually covering half the screen. My main goal here is privacy - I don't always want to *advertise* what I'm listening to.

For example, my Android music player looks like this while playing, I don't like the huge banner, displayed on half the screen:
[image]

VLC is a little better, but still has a banner covering a forth of the screen:
[image]

I know it's possible turning if off on the lock screen (which helps), and that I can removed album art altogether (but having thumbnails is nice) - but is there also a music player (or a skin) that doesn't display album art so prominently while playing?

Comment: i'm not 100% sure if it is what you want, but have you tried [VLC](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.videolan.vlc/)? (it has a setting at "Audio" to not use the art for lock screens.)

Comment: @DJCrashdummy - Thanks, VLC is pretty good, but could be better. I've added screenshots explaining what I don't like about the music player. The cover art could be explicit, but mostly it isn just something I don't want to share. I don't like it when people know what I'm listening to. 

Answer (score 2):

Pulsar has the ability to disable artwork (Settings->Show Artwork).

It comes in both a [Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.pulsar) and [Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.pulsar.pro) version. The Pro version adds more themes and things like an equalizer, but even the free version includes the ability to disable album art and is a very useable music player.

Answer (score 1):

[PowerAmp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer) has a 'Force Default Image' setting that prevents it from showing the actual album art.